# Define a relation $\sim$ on $\Bbb R$ by $x\sim y\iff x-y\in\Bbb Z$. Show for any $x\in\Bbb{R}$, there is a unique $y\in [0,1)$ such that $x\sim y$.

Tags: relations

b) Show that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, there is a unique $y \in [0,1)$ such that $x \sim y$.

In part a), I've proven that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation.

I'm stuck on how to put my thoughts into a proof for b.

I've gotten that for any $x$, then $y$ would just be the decimal portion of $x$.

e.g. $x=3.123$ then $y=.123$ since $x-y=3.123-.123 \in \mathbb{Z}$

Basically my question is: Is it supposed to be $y=$ something and how do I turn that into a proof?

Comment: You have correctly identified $y$. It's usually called the _fractional part_ of $x$, not the _decimal portion_.

Comment: You've shown existence-- to put this formally, you might be interested in writing $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ as its decimal expansion. For uniqueness, I would prove that for any $x,y$ in the given equivalence class of $\sim$, it must hold that $\|x-y\| \geq 1$. The result follows.

Comment: You need to show both uniqueness and existence. For uniqueness, suppose that for some $x$ there are two numbers $y$ and $z$ in $[0,1)$ such that $x~y$ and $x~z$; then use the definition and properties of $~$ to show $y=z$. For existence, any real $x$ is in an interval $[a,a+1)$ for some integer $a$. We can always subtract 1 (or -1 if $x$ is negative) and get another number equivalent to $x$ try using this together with the properties of an equivalence relation to show you can always find $y\in [0,1)$ with $x~y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we want to show that

- there exists
- a unique

$y \in [0, 1)$ such that $x \sim y$. We have to prove both assertions.

You have the right idea for the existence part. Subtract off the integer part. There's actually a notation for this, using the floor function:
$$
\lfloor x \rfloor = \max \{ n \in \mathbb{Z} \mid n \leq x \}.
$$
By the way, if you're trying to be rigorous, you have to show that the floor function is well-defined, i.e. that the set of integers has a maximum. Can you see how to do that?

A direct consequence of $N = \lfloor x \rfloor \in \mathbb{Z}$ is that
$$
N \leq x < N+1.
$$
Can you see how?

Now, we define $y$ to be the remainder:
$$
y = x - \lfloor x \rfloor = x - N. 
$$

The previous inequality directly implies that
$$
0 \leq y < 1, 
$$
as desired. This establishes *existence.*

For *uniqueness,* suppose that we have $y_1, y_2 \in [0, 1)$ such that $x \sim y_1$ and $x \sim y_2$. Since we have established that this is an equivalence relation, $y_1 \sim y_2$. Can you see how this implies that $y_1 = y_2$? Hence, the representative $y$ is unique.

Answer (score 1):

Take $y\in\mathbb{R}$. Let $[y]$ be the inferior integer part of $y$. Then $y-[y]\in [0,1)$.

If $x\sim y$ and $x,y\in [0,1)$ then

$0\leq y-x=k< 1$

So we are looking for an integer $k$ less than $1$. Hence $k=0$ and $x=y$.

This answer to question $b)$.

Remark: Take $p\colon \mathbb{R}\to S^1$ sending $\alpha$ to $e^{2\pi i\alpha}$. Then you can observe that $p$ can be factorised by the quotient map $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. This provide us a map $p\colon \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\to S^1$. I leave you to prove that is an homeomorphism. Thus $ \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\cong S^1$.

This could be also another way to prove the statement $b)$.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is essentially correct. We can formalize it with the floor and fractional part functions:

- $\newcommand{\floor}[1]{\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor}
  \newcommand{\fp}[1]{\left\{ #1 \right\}}
  \floor{x}$ is the largest integer $\le x$, i.e. $\floor{x} := \max \{ k \in \mathbb{Z} \mid k \le x \}$
- $\fp{x}$ is the fractional part, defined by $\fp{x} := x - \floor{x}$

Here, then, you want $y = \fp{x}$.

Correspondingly, $y \in [0,1)$ and $x - y = x - \fp{x} = x - (x-\floor{x})= \floor{x} \in \mathbb{Z}$.

---

If you don't want to appeal to alternative functions, do so with decimal expansions. Write

$$x := u\sum_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} d_i 10^i = \pm \cdots d_3d_2d_1d_0 . d_{-1}d_{-2}d_{-3} \cdots$$

where $d_i = 0$ for all sufficiently large $i$, and $d_i \in \{0,1,2,\cdots,9\}$ generally. Finally, $u \in \{+1,-1\}$, in order to account for the sign of $x$.

Then the $y$ you want is

$$y := \begin{cases}
\displaystyle \sum_{i = -\infty}^{-1} d_i 10^i =   0.d_{-1}d_{-2}d_{-3} \cdots & x \ge 0 \\
1 - \displaystyle \sum_{i = -\infty}^{-1} d_i 10^i & x < 0
\end{cases}
$$

---

Uniqueness in either framework I leave up to you, but it's fairly straightforward.